# PushContentStream() is not working in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core

This is my code same thing I have done asp.net framework, It is working fine in .net but Now I migrated the code to asp.net core, now it's not working.

```
public async void onStreamAvailable(Stream outputStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext context){
try
            {
               string fileName = $"{inputSessionId}.wav";  

                //Validate file availability
                if (await cloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName).ExistsAsync())
                {
                    blockBlob = cloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);                    
                    Stream blobStream = blockBlob.OpenReadAsync().Result;

                    //here set the size of buffer, you can set any size  
                    var buffer = new byte[65536];
                    using (var f = blockBlob.OpenReadAsync().Result)
                    {
                        var length = (int)f.Length;
                        var bytesRead = 1;
                        while (length > 0 && bytesRead > 0)
                        {
                            //here we are reading the buffer from orginal file
                            bytesRead = f.Read(buffer, 0, Math.Min(length, buffer.Length));

                            //here we are writing the readed buffer to output
                            await outputStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                            length -= bytesRead;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

// I am calling this method from here

```
Action<Stream, HttpContent, TransportContext> writeToStream = audioStream.onStreamAvailable;
   response.Content = new PushStreamContent(writeToStream, new MediaTypeHeaderValue("audio/wav"));
   return response;
```

Comment: Can you add breakpoints and share more debugging information?

Comment: @Jason, it seems , it doesn't call onstreamavailable(),                                              debug value for final response ------ response = {StatusCode: 200, ReasonPhrase: 'OK', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.PushStreamContent, Headers:
{
  Content-Type: audio/wav
}, Trailing Headers:
{
}}

Comment: You need show more code about `audioStream`,  so that we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: @Jason audio stream just class just contains following                                              public AudioStream(string sessionId)
        {
            inputSessionId = sessionId;
        }
        public async void onStreamAvailable(Stream outputStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext context)
        {}} ,I added breakpoint in the above method but cursor isn't goint there.

Answer (score 0):

I searched and found an alternative. As we know we can use `PushStreamContent` in `Asp.net`. In `Asp.net Core`, we need to rewrite it ourselves.

*To prevent the link from breaking, I will quote part of the code.*

```
class MyPushStreamResult :IActionResult
{
    Func<Stream, CancellationToken, Task> _pushAction;
    string _contentType;
 
    public MyPushStreamResult(Func<Stream, CancellationToken, Task> pushAction, string contentType)
    {
        _pushAction = pushAction;
        _contentType = contentType;
    }

    public Task ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
    {
        var response = context.HttpContext.Response;
        response.ContentType = _contentType;
        response.StatusCode = 200;
 

        return _pushAction(response.Body, context.HttpContext.RequestAborted);
    }
}
```

*The method of use is as follows:*

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Get()
{
    return new MyPushStreamResult(pushData, "text/html");
}
 
async Task pushData(Stream stream, CancellationToken cancel)
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (cancel.IsCancellationRequested)
            return;
        await Task.Delay(1000, cancel);
        var content = DateTime.Now + @"<br>";
        var data = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(content);
        await stream.WriteAsync(data, 0, data.Length, cancel);
        await stream.FlushAsync(cancel);
    }
}
```

Related post: [Return PushStream in Asp.net core](https://www.programmersought.com/article/98381674197/)